# Cross-validation and scores

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, cross-validation

I'm using training data set (i.e., X_train, y_train) when tuning the hyperparameters of my model. I need to use the test data set (i.e., X_test, y_test) as a final check, to make sure my model isn't biased.
I wrote

```
folds = 4

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size=(1/folds), random_state=38, stratify=y)

clf_logreg = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessing),
                      ('model', LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs', max_iter=100))])


cv = KFold(n_splits=(folds - 1))
scores_logreg = cross_val_score(clf_logreg, X_train, y_train, cv = cv)
```

and, to get f1-score,

```
cross_val_score(clf_logreg, X_train, y_train, scoring=make_scorer(f1_score, average='weighted'),
    cv=cv)
```

This returns

scores_logreg: `[0.94422311, 0.99335548, 0.97209302]`
and for f1: `[0.97201365, 0.9926906 , 0.98925453]`

For checking the test, is it right to write

```
cross_val_score(clf_logreg, X_test, y_test, scoring=make_scorer(f1_score, average='weighted'), cv=cv) # not sure if it is ok to let cv
```

or maybe

```
predicted_logreg= clf_logreg.predict(X_test)
f1 = f1_score(y_test, predicted_logreg)
```

Value returned are different.

Comment: have you tried using classification_report in sklearn.metrics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cross_val_score` is meant for scoring a model by cross-validation, if you do:

```
cross_val_score(clf_logreg, X_test, y_test, 
scoring=make_scorer(f1_score, average='weighted'), cv=cv)
```

You are putting redo-ing the cross validation on your test set, which does not make much sense except that you are now training your model on a smaller dataset, compared to your train.

I think the [help page on cross validation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html) on scikit learn illustrates it, you don't need to rerun a cross validation on your test set:

[image]

You just do:

```
predicted_logreg= clf_logreg.predict(X_test)
f1 = f1_score(y_test, predicted_logreg)
```

Comment: Thanks @StupidWolf. If I understand correctly, the right values should come from the last code you mentioned (predicted_logreg and f1), shouldn't they?